# Hide dynamic div element in javascript and/or html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of new at this so bear with me. I am trying to hide a specific dynamic div element (it's a catalog) out of a list of 6 elements (catalogs) but not having much luck. To be specific, catalogid="3" needs to be hidden on the page yet still remain active. If the exact url for that catalog is pasted into the browser, the catalog should be accessible. Basically, it is going to be a hidden catalog only given to specific customers in order to buy specific products.

Here is the HTML:

```
<span catalogLink='index.html?action=courseBrowse&CatalogID=${CatalogID}' style="color:#fff">${Name}</span>
```

And here is the Java script code:

```
 location.href =getHostingHTML()+"?action=courseBrowse&CatalogID="+catalogID;
```

Question: Can I just put a snip-it of code under either of those lines that would simply hide catalog 3 after execution?

Comment: if this is suppose to be only for privileged users then it should not be placed in the browser, anything you do to hide it can be undone.Are you using any server side technologies to serve your pages?

Comment: Hey Quince, thanks for the reply. The privileged users are the employees, the client isn't worried about them using a direct link to access the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to give this css attribute to the span element.

```
span {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Flopet17, thank you for the reply. The span needs to display the other 5 elements. Is there a way to label that snip-it specifying only one of the catalogs to be set to display:none;

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
span {
  display:none;
}
```

however, this will hide every span in your entire website. You might want to add a class to the specific span class you would like to hide:

```
<span class="hide-me" catalogLink='index.html?action=courseBrowse&CatalogID=${CatalogID}' style="color:#fff">${Name}</span>

<style type="text/css">

.hide-me{
   display:none;
}

</style>
```

additionally you could do this as well

```
<span catalogLink='index.html?action=courseBrowse&CatalogID=${CatalogID}' style="color:#fff; display:none;">${Name}</span>
```

Comment: Justin, could I possibly do something higher up in code to hide catalogid=3? Like here:`<td><a onclick="forwardToCourseBrowse(${CatalogID})">${Name}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span id='myspan' catalogLink='index.html?action=courseBrowse&CatalogID=${CatalogID}'style="color:#fff">${Name}</span>
```

I recomend to add an Id to your span, and then dinamically, in your javascript call the following:

```
document.getElementById("myspan").style["display"] = "none";
```

Comment: Hi Julian!! If I know the catalog ID in the database is 3, can I specify only that catalog to be hidden in the code you recommend?

Comment: If I do that msrd0, wouldn't it hide all 6 elements? I only want to hide element 3.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that would hide the entire catalog. Can you explore the HTML code of your catalog when it's generated? Find the way to call   univocally the element you want to hide (by id, by name, by class) and then apply display none as above